# shell when executed manually in console is working fine but when javascript executes it I am getting error from the script

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, firebase

The JavaScript code is

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./raniserverFBkey.json');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

exports.addSteamID1 = functions.firestore.document('steamIDs/{docID}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        const steamID = snap.data().steamID;
        exec(`./addvips.sh ${steamID} a`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${err}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });
    });
```

the shell script code is

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]
then
  echo "Error: Not enough arguments provided."
  exit 1
fi

data="\"$1\" \"$2\""
echo "$data" >> /home/ubuntu/serverfiles/csgo/addons/sourcemod/configs/admins_simple.ini

echo "Successfully appended '$data' to the file."
```

When I run the script using

```
./addvips.sh steamid a
```

the script is running fine and appending data to admins_simple.ini file successfully.

but when I run JavaScript code, the script is giving error

```
stderr: ./addvips.sh: line 10: /home/ubuntu/serverfiles/csgo/addons/sourcemod/configs/admins_simple.ini: No such file or directory
```

The JavaScript code is executed by Firebase cloud function.
name of JavaScript file is index.js and name of script is addvips.sh

Why is that script is running fine when executed manually in terminal but giving error when executed by JavaScript?

I have Firebase cloud function which is called whenever a new document is added to collection. The function is supposed to call the script addvips.sh which appends the added steam id to the collection and "a" to admins_simple.ini. I wrote a separate shell script for appending operation because when I tried to do that in the index.js itself using fs.appendFile I got the same error:

```
/home/ubuntu/serverfiles/csgo/addons/sourcemod/configs/admins_simple.ini: No such file or directory
```

also all of this is happening on a root volume of an EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

[directory containing index.js and addvips.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O41u1.png)

[directory containing admins_simple.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FFKN.png)

Comment: One of the directories in that path does not exist. You'll have to experiment to find out which one. The shell will not make all of them on the way to making the actual file at the end of the path.

Comment: You could try putting `mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/serverfiles/csgo/addons/sourcemod/configs` before `echo`, if the directories are all there it won't hurt anything but it will create them (if it does not encounter permission problems).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the index.js wasn't able to run the script successfully was because it was running on a google server and not my ec2 instance.